# Website loses css content when hosted on linux server

Tags: linux, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I have a website that is primarily html5 and css3, and the pages look good when I run them locally from my pc on chrome and internet explorer 11.0.47, but when I put it on the Linux server and run the page from there on my own pc, the page loses the css in IE but is fine in chrome.

I don't have a lot of experience with html5/css3.  What's going on here?  I tried googling it, but don't see any online help.

The web page is [start of web site](http://ltrkarkvm391.mgmt.windstream.net/catv/index.html).  As you can see, in IE, Map Home isn't shown as a button in nav to the left, and nav lost it's brown background.  It also lost the header background.  If you look at the link in chrome, it has those.

Any ideas? Could there be a directional issue with use of the media folder when IE pulls it from Linux but not chrome?

**Added:
I see this on the server log, but when I list the location on the server, the file exists there. The css file (catvStyles.css) referring to the globe file is in the same dir as index.html, and the media dir is in the dir of index.html.

> File does not exist:
>   /opt/apps/html/catv/media/globe_transp_gradation.png), url(..,
>   referer: http://ltrkarkvm391.mgmt.windstream.net/catv/index.html

**
This looks similar to [other web page](https://bronsonenterprises.000webhostapp.com/index.html) if you can't reach the link. The problem is my linux hosted site isn't showing the brown nav to the left, it's not showing the metal header globe, and windmill pictures, and it's not showing Map Home in a button (it's as a link without the button), and it's not showing the picture in the right side to the right (it's in the body now).

This is the index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="FunStuff/catvStyles.css">
<title>CATV Monitoring</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="Wi">
<meta name="keywords" content="catv, cmts, snmp, modem, dhcp, rf, status, map">
<meta name="author" content="Wi, Michele, Adam">

<style type="text/css">


</style>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"> </script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <header role="banner" class="bgFun">
    <h1>Wi</h1>
    <h2 id="headerH2Pos">CATV Monitoring System</h2>
  </header>
  <div id="page">
  <nav role="navigation" id="navBakImg">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="FunStuff/ClusterMap.html">Map Home</a></li> <!--MapHome.html-->

    </ul>
   </nav>

   <main role="main" id="middle">
    <h2>Purpose</h2>
    <p>To provide CATV Monitoring to our internal customers</p>
     </p>
    <h2>Mapping </h2>
    <p>Click the "Map Home" link on the left to see how the network is doing </p>
    <img class="imgFix" src="media/WIN_Vert_Green_Logo.png"  height:"18" width:"15" alt="Logo" title="Wi" >
     </p>
    </main>
    <aside role="complementary">
      <img class="imgFix" src="media/WIN_Vert_Green_Logo.png"  height:"18" width:"15" alt="Logo" title="Wi" >
     <h2>How To Start</h2>
     <p>See directions</p>
   </aside>
   </div> <!-- end of flex container -->
   <footer role="contentinfo">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michele" target="_blank"><img class="tree" src="media/Tree_Branches_And_Roots_clip_art_small.png"  height="50" width="50" alt="Tree" title="Created by Michele " ></a>
      <br>Copyright &copy; 2017
      <script>
        document.write('Last Modified: ' + document.lastModified);
      </script>
  <br>

   </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the css catvStyles.css:

```
body {font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      background-color: #330000;
      background-image: url(../media/green.gif);


}
#middle{}
header, h1, wrapper { margin-top: 0; }
#wrapper {  background-color: #F4E8BC;
            /*background-color: #00ffff;*/
            width: 90%;
            margin: auto;
            color: #003300;/*color: #330000;*/

}
h1, h2 { color: #003300; }
header {
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color:transparent;
}
.bgFun{background-image: url(../media/globe_transp_gradation.png),
         url(../media/windmill_transp_gradation.png),url(../media/MetalGalvanized0014_M.jpg);
         background-position: left, right;
         /*width: 80%;
         height:80%;*/
         background-size:45%,30%,cover;
         background-repeat:no-repeat;
         background-color:transparent;}
h1 { text-align: center;
      font-size: 300%;
     padding: 5% 0;
     text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #F4E8BC;
}
nav, main, aside {  padding: 0 1em;
}
.imgFix { width: 25%;
      height: auto;
}
nav ul { list-style-type: none;
         font-size: 1.2em;
         padding-left: 0;
}
/*nav a { text-decoration: none;}*/
nav a {
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: #666666;
   display:block;
   text-align:center;
   width:100%;
   margin:1em auto;
   border:solid .08em #339900
}
nav a:link { color: #330000; }
nav a:visited { color: #003300; }
nav a:hover { color: #996600;
              background-color:#000000;}
footer { text-align: center;
         font-size: 80%;
         font-style: italic;
         color: #003300;
         padding: 2.5%;
}
#page{display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-direction: row;
      flex-direction: row;
}
#navBakImg{border: .1em solid #000000;
    padding-right:1em;
    background-image: url(../media/CardboardPlain0016_2_M.jpg);
    font-size:90%;}
nav{-webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
main{-webkit-flex: 7;
     flex:7;
}
aside{-webkit-flex: 2;
      flex: 2;
}
.tree { width:3em;
        height: auto;
        float:right;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
            body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
            #wrapper { width: auto; margin: 0; }
            h1 { font-size: 200%; }
            nav li { padding: 0 0.5em;
                     font-size: 1.2em;
                    }
        #page{-webkit-flex-direction: column;
                  flex-direction: column;
            }
            nav ul{display: -webkit-flex;
                   display: flex;
                   -webkit-flex-direction: row;
                   flex-direction: row;
                   webkit-justify-content: center;
                   justify-content: center;
            }
            .imgFix { width: 30%;
            height: auto;}


}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
            nav{-webkit-order: 1;
                order: 1;
            }
            nav ul{-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
                   flex-wrap: wrap;
            }
            section{display:none;}
            .imgFix { width: 35%;
            height: auto;}
}
header, main, nav, footer, figure, figcaption { display: block; }
#headerH2Pos{position:relative;
             left:26%;
             }
```

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: I can reach the link. Maybe it's just open to me because I work there. I can't open it to you.

Comment: If we can’t replicate the problem, it’s going to be tough to help

Comment: Can you test without using relative paths (`url(../media/globe_transp_gradation.png)` => `url(/media/globe_transp_gradation.png)`). I know that relative paths let you view the files directly from a development machine's hard drive, but this prevents you from experiencing issues that might come up when using an actual server.

Comment: I tried moving the index.html's css file to the same dir and then didn't need .. for that page and it still didn't find the globe file. Plus I changed the path, of course, to the css file to be in the same dir. Should I post that code now?  I didn't want to take away the code above if someone was looking at it. The path for that would be media/globe_transp_gradation.png then without the / in front.

Comment: I tried changing the location of just the globe file to be in the same dir as index now, but the error on the server has changed in a way I wouldn't expect. "File does not exist: /opt/apps/html/catv2/globe_transp_gradation.png"),url("media, referer: http://ltrkarkvm391.mgmt.windstream.net/catv2/index.html" So now instead of ../media/globe, it's media, but I got rid of the media part of the path to globe.  There isn't a reference in index or catv_styles now for globe being in the media dir. I'm not sure why it's showing media in the server error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this line and it was fixed:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Looks like it's something else, as Michele says it works in Chrome but not IE when served from Linux.

---

Judging by your filenames, you may have just encountered a Windows => Linux gotcha:

The Linux filesystem is Case Sensitive, Windows is case insensitive.

You'll need to double check that you're using the right casing in your URLs, else the file won't be found when Linux goes to look for it.

Comment: If that was the case, I think chrome would have the same issue and it doesn't.  Good idea, though!

Comment: That's not it.  IDK why people keep up-voting it.

Comment: @Michele - We're uprooting it because it's an important thing to note. This might not be the solution for your issue, but it is something that will help other people visiting this page.

Comment: @Michele - don't discard this as a solution. It might be that IE or chrome are changing the case of the provided file names after a failed attempt. I would definitely change all file names to down_case. Having upper case letters in file names is just asking for trouble. Consider the next time you update a file and it saves it in an alternate spelling just because of a different letter case spelling...

Comment: I added a similar web page link in case it helps. The other web page isn't hosted on the linux server and works fine.

Comment: I tried making the directory and filenames all lower case and it didn't fix it.  I also tried moving the files to the same dir as they were referred to from, and it didn't help either.